# Is there a way to pretty print SELECT query result in ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

Alternative in ClickHouse Select query to pretty print like in MySQL vertically.

For example -

```sql
SELECT * from table \g;
```

I found this resource but its just text
https://clickhouse-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats/vertical.html

With --multiline as a parameter for clickhouse-client I am getting following error . Though i can use \G format as per one of the answer without this param :

```
 :) select * from hits_v1 limit 2; \G
:-] ;

Syntax error (Multi-statements are not allowed): failed at position 30 (end of query):

select * from hits_v1 limit 2; \G ;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ClickHouse supports [this feature](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/cli/#cli_usage):

> You can specify \G instead of or after the semicolon. This indicates Vertical format.

```sql
select * from numbers(2)\G
/* result
Row 1:
──────
number: 0

Row 2:
──────
number: 1
*/
```

```sql
select * from numbers(2);\G
/* result
Row 1:
──────
number: 0

Row 2:
──────
number: 1
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i am using click house-client with --multiline parameter and in that case its not working.  However it works without --multiline argument.Edited my question with details

Answer (score 7):

Well, it was quick. I have to use FORMAT Parameter :

```sql
select * from hits_v1  limit 100  FORMAT Vertical;
```

More to study here :
https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/formats/